# Easy with the sudo - Yo webapp

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman

I get an error while running yo webapp as "Easy with the sudo. Yeoman is the master around here"

Please help me out. I followed the same instructions in the yoeman.io website.

Without sudo , on running in /usr/node/ with the directory changed to 777 with chmod,

Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/manish/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
    at Object.create.all.set (/home/manish/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:39:7)
    at Object.Configstore (/home/manish/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:30:11)
    at new Insight (/home/manish/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js:20:16)
    at Object. (/home/manish/local/lib/node_modules/yo/bin/yo:26:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you must be trying to start your application as root.

See this for more information: https://github.com/passy/yo/commit/d33e7a67d74343d836a14881b17b3072b92f2532

If you're starting your applciation by running:

```
sudo node app.js
```

Try doing this instead:

```
node app.js
```

I.e. this won't try to start the application as root.

Same goes for scaffolding, if you're trying to create your application. you shouldn't need sudo for that if you're doing that under your home (~/) directory.

Comment: Cool.. but I am talking about scaffolding an app with "Yo webapp". If i dont run it as root, i am getting the error that I dont have permission to run it since i am not root .

Comment: Where are you trying to create your app? If you try and create it under your ~/ directory, then it should work without sudo

Comment: under /usr/node. So what should i do to create an app under /usr/node ?

Comment: If you ant to create under usr/node, then you'd need to be root, but that' totally the wrong place to do it. This is where node will be installed. you should really do it under your user account.

Comment: Cool, make sure to mark the question as answered if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Gist here with a selection of shell scripts to help you install Node and NPM without requiring sudo permissions:

https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

Comment: I ran the first one in this link and while I get no problems using node and npm without sudo I still have the same error for yo. I am documenting with some detail here and getting some help - https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1292

Answer (score 0):

So running yo ? gives the error above - maybe like for me it installed ~/Users/yourusername/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml with the root permissions and this needs chowning to the name of the user.

chown yourusername ~/Users/yourusername/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml

This was my issue and may be a part of the full solution given here https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814